# How to make these type of vector in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, information-graphics

[image: I want to make the vector of persons standing in surrounding like this picture]

I want to create a vector like the one attached. which tool in illustrator would help to create vector like this?

Comment: Bottom right image is not vector art: it's a 3D model and render. All others either use a method similar to Danielillo's excellent answer or simply draw the art with a vector pen and snapping; one thin I would add to Danielillo's approach - set a perspective percentage in the 3D Extrude and Bevel tool for a closer match to the bottom left of the example images.

Answer (score 6):

Illustrator:

Make the shapes and create a Symbol with them

[image: shapes]

Make a circle and go the menu Effect → 3D → Extrude and Bevel

[image]

Click Map Art, select the side shape and add the Symbol.

Adjust the size and click **Invisible Geometry**

[image]

[image]